# Readkey in Java

Tags: java, console, console.readkey

I am new to Java ... is there a similar method to the ReadKey() in C# to avoid that a console application closes?

thanks

Comment: I am just curious, what's the point to avoid the closing of a console application?

Comment: i am running a database query, and after it displays the result, the console window immediately closes.

Comment: i am coding in a textpad and then compile and run using cmd

Comment: @PetarMinchev, IDE doesn't make any difference. When you are running a java application from explorer (such as windows explorer) if application do not wait for user input, its window will close immediately.

Comment: Title the post with your actual question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
br.readLine();
```

there are definitely shorter ones, but I think this one's convenient, because it can easily be extended.

Comment: *"I am new to Java"* other newbies take delight in knowing to `import java.io.BufferedReader;` (and `import java.io.InputStreamReader;`).

Comment: I think this will read input until `enter` key pressed. ReadKey only wait and read for a single any character.

Answer (score 19):

YOu can also use `System.in.read()`, if you are ok with just 'Enter' key being your exit key.