# How do I read the next keypress from user in Java

Tags: java

I would like to be able to read the next key the user presses into the console, I have not been able to find anything that was working, and by the way I am pretty new to Java. It should work like Console.Readkey() in C# .

What it should not require `enter` to read the key. The answer on [readkey in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533987/readkey-in-java) does not seem to work that way. Else I would like an answer that explains how it works

Comment: Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your Name.");
String name=sc.nextLine();

Comment: Would you call `Enter` a key ?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533987/readkey-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Readkey in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533987/readkey-in-java)

Comment: Well it doesn't look like it is working

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String x = scan.nextLine();
String y = scan.nextLine();
```

---

To print your value you can use :

```
System.out.println("X = " + x);
System.out.println("Y = " + y);
```